# Applying css when converting html to pdf

Tags: css, vb.net, itext

I am having problem with my code while converting html to pdf. The css is not applied even when i am using

```
StyleSheet.LoadStyle("class_name", "font-size", "24px")
```

and then passing to this

```
Dim parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StringReader(content), obj)
```

Now, when the pdf file is created the css is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I dynamically inserted a CSS file when converting.

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        ' If we are in print mode, it's time to format the page for PDF generation
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("print")) Then
            ' Dynamically add a LINK element to the page that points to the 
            ' print-ready CSS styles
            Dim printCSS As New HtmlLink
            printCSS.Href = "~/Framework/Styles/pdf.css"
            printCSS.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet")
            printCSS.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css")
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(printCSS)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```